# Issues with setting up react native cli project

Tags: ruby, react-native

When I run `npx react-native projectname`, the project is only created partially.

Now when I run `bundle install` I get:

`1. Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

`2. An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.5), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that "gem install ffi -v '1.15.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'" succeeds before bundling.`

```console
Using atomos 0.1.3
Using bundler 2.1.4
Using claide 1.1.0
Using fuzzy_match 2.0.4
Using nap 1.1.0
Using netrc 0.11.0
Fetching ffi 1.15.5
Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: █████████████████████s/React
Native/uber/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
█████████████████████/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20221129-56735-3mfz1o.rb
extconf.rb
checking for ffi_prep_closure_loc() in -lffi… no
checking for ffi_prep_closure_loc() in -llibffi… no
checking for ffi_prep_closure_loc() in -llibffi-8… no
checking for whether -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL is accepted as LDFLAGS… no
checking for whether -pthread is accepted as LDFLAGS… yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

current directory: █████████████████████React
Native/uber/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: █████████████████████React
Native/uber/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR="
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** █████████████████████ Error 2

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in █████████████████████/React
Native/uber/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5 for inspection.
Results logged to █████████████████████/React
Native/uber/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-21/2.7.0/ffi-1.15.5/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.15.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  cocoapods was resolved to 1.11.3, which depends on
    cocoapods-core was resolved to 1.11.3, which depends on
      typhoeus was resolved to 1.4.0, which depends on
        ethon was resolved to 0.16.0, which depends on
          ffi
```

Yes, I have installed the ffi 1.15.5 (below screenshot) but it is still saying I dont have it

```console
█████████████████████ gem install ffi -v '1.15.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/ '
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.15.5
Parsing documentation for ffi-1.15.5
Done installing documentation for ffi after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

**Ruby version**: ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [arm64-darwin21]

**pod** --version: 1.11.3

I am impressed how difficult it is to start a project. Someone please help

Answer (score 0):

Try using expo. https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/create-a-new-app/

run `npx create-expo-app my-app`
this will create a new app called "my-app".

Or you could run `npx create-expo-app --template` to begin with a starter app. I like to use 'Navigation (TypeScript)'.

The expo link will explain how to set up your app and how to run your app in a simulator or with the expo go app on your phone. It's a great resource.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Expo runs flawlessly, but I am trying to learn RN CLI